# Inserting text from a file to the beginning of another file - bash

Tags: bash, insert, sed

I am trying to insert some copy-right information into the beginning of some source files. I know that using sed in the following way:

```
sed "1iSome copyrighted information." sample.txt
```

would insert the text "Some copyrighted information" to the beginning of sample.txt.
I need to insert text from a file to the beginning of sample.txt. Is there any way in sed that I could use a `cat` command for the above purpose, say something like the following?:

```
sed "1i{cat header.txt}" sample.txt
```

I have googled for the above and have not found exactly what I have been looking for. Any help on this is most welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use ed text editor:

```
echo -e '0r header.txt\nw' | ed sample.txt
```

or use vi/ex command:

```
vi - +'0r header.txt|wq' sample.txt
```

But I don't see any way to run a command in sed.

Answer (score 11):

Sorry to use up a whole answer - just for the sake of formatting :) Basically, the same answer from @tangens, but without the temporary file:

```
echo "$(cat header.txt sample.txt)" > sample.txt
```

Note the quotes (`"`) to preserve the line endings, and the fact that the `cat` concatenation runs in a subprocess - so there shouldn't be the possibility of overwriting a file (the `sample.txt`) which is open for reading..

Cheers!

Answer (score 10):

If you have GNU `sed`:

```
sed -i -e '2{x;G};1{h;rheader.txt' -e 'd}' sample.txt
```

sample.txt must be contain at least two lines.

This method works even if the header file contains characters that are special to `sed`.

Explanation:

- `-i` - edit the file in place
- `-e` - break the script up into sections - this is necessary in this case to delimit the end of the header filename (it could also be delimited by a newline)
- `1{h;` - on the first line of the file (sample.txt) save it to hold space
- `rheader.txt` - read in the header file (header.txt)
- `d}` - delete the original first line of the file from pattern space and end processing of line 1 - deleting it here prevents an extra blank line from being inserted at the beginning of the file
- the header file contents are now output
- `2{x;` - when line 2 of the file (sample.txt) is read, swap it into hold space and swap hold space (containing the original line 1) into pattern space
- `G}` - append hold space onto the end of pattern space (which now contains original lines 1 and 2) and complete processing of line 2
- lines 1 and 2 are now output then processing continues for the rest of the file which consists of simply reading and outputting each line.

**Edit:** I removed a superfluous command from the version I originally posted.

Comment: how would you recursively [with condition] apply this to all files in a folder ? 
e.g : `for all subfolders/files in . : if file is *.c then SED_CMD` ??

Comment: @bny: One way (for Bash 4): `shopt -s globstar; for file in ./**/*.c; do [[ -f $file ]] && SED_CMD; done`. You would use `"$file" as the filename argument to `sed`. You could use `find` and `xargs` instead of the `for` loop if, for example, you're using a previous version of Bash.

Answer (score 5):

```
cat header.txt sample.txt > temp.txt
mv temp.txt sample.txt
```

Comment: that will put header underneath sample

Comment: This will append sampte.txt to header.txt. The order is correct. After your comment I tried it again. It works.

Comment: You can do this on one line... "cat header.txt sample.txt > temp.txt && mv temp.txt sample.txt" ... pretty understandable once youve used it once.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it using `sed`:

```
INFO=$(cat header.txt)  # read the contents of file headers.txt into var INFO
sed -i "1i$INFO" sample.txt # insert $INFO, use -i to change the file inplace
```

I would however use the `cat` based method.

Comment: I think this method wouldn't work if your header contains some strings that sed interprets as a command.

Comment: tangens is right, that does not work. the header.txt contains information in the form of C-style comments (/* and */) which sed interprets as a command.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this the other way round, e.g. append your source files to your copyright file?

The 'cat' command is actually short for 'concatenate', you can simply say

```
for f in *.c
do
    cp $f /tmp
    cat copyright.txt /tmp/$f >$f
done
```

Comment: You have a major cleanup problem in /tmp - and that assumes you aren't working in /tmp in the first place!

Comment: Not really, that's what /tmp is for. If you're happy you just rm them, if you're not, you've guaranteed that you can undo the change.