# Retroactively apply Netbeans template

Tags: templates, netbeans, ant

I have a project with a decent number of files, and but I've only now come to licensing it. I have my license template all set up, but none of the files in my project were built after this template was created. Is there a way to retroactively apply this header template to automatically give all the files in my project license headers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with just Netbeans no, but [maven-license-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-license-plugin/) should do exactly what you want.

Alternatively, you could [use sed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3784886/800764). (This what I ended up doing.)

Comment: my project is ant, so I assume the maven plugin doesn't work. Thanks for the point to sed.